# Ejecutar HTML y JS desde PHP y recibir respuesta

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy haciendo un webservice, necesito hacer un PDF con jsPDF, pero estoy trabajando con PHP, y necesito ejecutar ese javascript desde otra url, he intentado con curl, pero me regresa todo el HTML sin ejecutar el javascript, como puedo hacer una simulación de javascript? o simular un explorador con PHP?

Este es mi código:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable"></script>
<script>
    function resultPdf() {
        // Mi código para mostrar en el HTML
    }

    //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = resultPdf();

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'PRUEBA';
</script>
```

Lo que quiero que me muestre es "PRUEBA", dentro del div.

Comment: y no puedes mejor generar el archivo desde PHP?

Comment: a ver si entendí, lo que quieres es ejecutar código de JavaScript desde PHP?

Comment: @Alx, Sí, porque ya tengo todo el código para el PDF en JavaScript de otra parte de mi sistema que lo ejecuta en JS, quería saber si es posible para no tener que hacer todo otra vez en PHP

Comment: por que no. en el servicie retornas un `url`  y en el ` front end`  utilizas un `iframe` para mostrar el pdf

Comment: Haz caso a lo que te sugiere @Pipe, lo demás es complicarte la vida, sobrecargando el entorno del cliente con librerías externas como `jsPDF`. Desde PHP, con poner un [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) del tipo [`Content-disposition: inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) generarías el PDF en el navegador, que es lo que pareces necesitar. Ya veo sugerencias como usar un `iframe`, etc. ¿Por qué optar por el camino largo cuando PHP dispone de mejores herramientas para esto?

Comment: entonces es muy facil, solo hay que convertir todo el codigo de java script  a una cadena y ejecutarlo con un **echo**, Solo ten cuidado con las comillas y los apostrofes para no romper la cadena

Answer (score 0):

```
$CODIGO_JAVA_SCRIPT = "<div id='content'></div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js'></script>
<script>
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
</script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable'></script>
<script>
    function resultPdf() {
        // Mi código para mostrar en el HTML
    }

    //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = resultPdf();

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'PRUEBA';
</script>";

echo $CODIGO_JAVA_SCRIPT;
```